# (p4 api .NET) Overwriting revision specification error when using Client.EditFiles

Tags: c#, .net, perforce

```
con.Client.EditFiles(foundFiles, new Options(EditFilesCmdFlags.None, changelist.Id, null));
```

I am currently getting the error "A revision specification (# or @) cannot be used here" when running this line of code.  I am suspecting that it is because some of my files in foundFiles contain a "#" symbol in their names.  Can anyone confirm this is the problem?  And does anyone know a way around it?  I had a similar error with Client.AddFiles, but I could use the AddFilesCmdFlags.KeepWildcards to invoke the -f (force) flag to bypass this.  Unfortunately the same doesn't work for EditFiles.

NOTE: I cannot change the name of the files, as there are thousands and it is not in my jurisdiction to change them in any way.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
Options opts = new Options(EditFilesCmdFlags.None, changelist.Id, null);
con.Client.EditFiles(FileSpec.UnversionedSpecList(foundFiles), opts);
```

UnversionedSpecList is a static function in FileSpec that allows you to pass in your list of FileSpecs and it will strip away the versions for you.